# Comunicacion entre dos Aplicativos externos sin Comunicacion Constante en el mismo celular

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, ciclo-de-vida

tengo una duda como hacer que dos aplicativos (A-B) reviva al otro si uno muere.
ejm: si el aplicativo A es (desinstalado, se crasheo, se detuvo, etc), el aplicativo B lo tiene que volver a instalar y viceversa

Mis pensamientos fueron, integrar un ciclo de vida y que al momento que entre en onDestroy iniciara un intent

```
override fun onDestroy() {
        Log.i("Ciclo de Vida", "metodo onDestroy")
val launchIntent = packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("aplicativo B")
        startActivity(launchIntent)
 }
```

y que al aplicativo B tuviera en su onCreate un intent de del aplicativo A,
pero el aplicativo A llegaba al ondestroy no enviaba el intent
y eso que me faltaria del aplicativo A reviva al aplicativo B si muere

Alguna Sugerencia o librerias que me puedan ayudar con esta actividad

PD: lo estoy intentando hacer en Kotlin

Answer (score 1):

Para realizar lo que deseas es importante revisar acerca de "Visibilidad de paquetes", ya que desde Android 11 debes definir en tu archivo `AndroidManifest.xml` los paquetes de aplicaciones con los cuales tu aplicación va a interactuar:

```
<manifest package="com.example.game">
    <queries>
        <package android:name="com.juan.appb" />
        <package android:name="com.whatsapp" />
        <package android:name="com.juan.appc" />
    </queries>
    ...
    ...
</manifest>
```

De esta forma podras realizar el Intent para realizar la instalación de la "app B".

---

Con respecto a:

> no se ejecuta cuando ingresa al OnDestroy() el intent; si funciona el
> intent con el OnPause()

Al llamar en `onDestroy()` la activity se encuentra en proceso de destrucción, en este punto puedes no tener el contexto, lo cual es necesario para iniciar la activity (`startActivity()`), por lo tanto lo ideal es mandar cargar la activity cuando esta esta lista para ser eliminada, en este caso sería `onPause()`.

Comment: Hola y gracias por responder, Si tengo integrado los Queries en el manifest, para los intent, solo que  me referia que no se ejecuta cuando ingresa al OnDestroy() el intent;
 si funciona el intent con el OnPause(), pero no es lo que deseo, porque hago uso de libreria accesibility para activar los datos en caso lo apagara el usuario.
aun asi sigo en la busqueda de algun metodo de hacer que el usuario no pueda eliminar el Aplicativo A , B en celulares No Root, por eso trato de que uno reviva al otro si es eliminado, solo que deseo hacerlo sin comunicacion constante

Comment: Si, debes realizar la carga de la activity dentro de onPause(), ya que en onDestroy() el contexto puede ya no existir.